# What causes the cracked floor in Petra to break?

Tags: overwatch

In the Petra map, there is a [floor that can be broken](https://www.pcgamer.com/overwatchs-newest-deathmatch-map-petra-has-a-breakable-floor-and-lethal-pits/). What causes this to happen?

Answer (score 4):

The floor will break after a random amount of damage has been dealt do the object.

Every tile can be broken, and some heroes seem to deal more damage than others.

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/8minih/how_much_health_does_the_floor_at_petra_have/

Comment: Thanks for the response, but your source seems to indicate that it takes 1300-1400 damage, not a random amount

Comment: I'm also curious if certain ults might affect the floor more than others. For example, would Earth Shatter or Meteor Strike do more to break the floor than just the amount of damage that they would normally cause?